# Converting JPEG and other types to TGA

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, jpeg, tga

I am trying to create a mass image converter for common image types. I was able to find a [TGA reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31702/NET-Targa-Image-Reader) and I can convert TGA to image types supported by .NET library. However, there is no converter of "something" to TGA in .NET except the external dll files with .NET wrappers. I don't have any experience with GDI+ objects which are apperantly the key for conversion. So is there any example or idea that can get me started? Or is there a very simple way that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.imagemagick.org/ - ImageMagick is a very useful cross-platform tool for converting from one image type to another. You can use the included command-line utilities to do batch conversions. It supports TGA (among many other formats).